# Ag-grid cell Render html or template with function()

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I am rendering cell template when on click it should perform some function.My Bellow code is not working.Thanks in Advance

```
             {
                field: "expiry_date",
                headerName: "End date"
              },{
                field:"Reserved Date",
               // template: `<p (click)='open()'>Reserve Date</p>`,
               cellRenderer: function (params) {
                var html = `<p (click)=${this.open(params.data)}'>Reserve Date</p>`;
        
                return html;
            }
```

Comment: Please include the error that you are getting as well.

Comment: I am not getting error.but it is not working for me as the implementation is wrong

Answer (score 1):

We can bind the method and it's label with help of `cellRendererParams` of *ag-grid* library.

You can do this like below,

```
        {
            field: "expiry_date",
            headerName: "End date"
        },
        {
            field:"Reserved Date",
            cellRendererParams: {
                    onClick: this.open.bind(this),
                    label: 'Reserve Date'
            }
        }
```

You can read more about cellRenderParams here: [component-cell-renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/component-cell-renderer/#complementing-cell-renderer-params)

Comment: Please explore more on attached document for possible ways to solve your queries..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new cellRendererComponent.
Something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { ICellRendererParams, IAfterGuiAttachedParams } from 'ag-grid-community';


@Component({
  selector: 'cpl-button-renderer',
  template: `
    <button type="button" (click)="onClick($event)">{{label}}</button>
    `,
    styles: []
})

export class ButtonRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {

  params;
  label: string;

  agInit(params): void {
    this.params = params;
    this.label = this.params.label || null;
  }

  refresh(params?: any): boolean {
    return true;
  }

  onClick($event) {
    if (this.params.onClick instanceof Function) {
      // put anything into params u want pass into parents component
      const params = {
        event: $event,
        rowData: this.params.node.data
        // ...something
      }
      this.params.onClick(params);

    }
  }
}
```

From the parent component, You need to add it to framework object of aggrid, and provide it in columnDefs:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.frameworkComponents = {
            buttonRenderer: ButtonRendererComponent,
        }
    }
```

ColumnDefs:

```
       {
            headerName: 'Button Demo',
            cellRenderer: 'buttonRenderer',
            cellRendererParams: {
                onClick: this.open.bind(this),
                label: 'Reserve Date'
            }
        },
```

Add open function like this:

```
private open(params) {
    // do whatever you want.
    // Params will contain the oject that you passed in .onclick method of renderer component     
}
```

HTML file:

```
<ag-grid-angular style="height: 450px;" class="ag-theme-alpine" [rowData]="rowData"
            [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
            [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents">
</ag-grid-angular>
```